# validate MySQL select query processed successfully

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

What i'm trying is validate a select query is processed successfully.
With DB transaction we can validate **INSERT , UPDATE, DELETE**

like shown below in Codeigniter

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
//query
if($this->db->trans_status() == false){                 
     return ['error' => 1, 'message' => 'Error massage'];          
}
```

but it does not work with **SELECT query**. 
Is there any other ways to validate this.

Actually my select query will be like this in a scenario

```
SELECT (amount1+ 10 / 100) FROM test_table
```

the formula **(amount1+ 10 / 100)** in the above query will be decoded from the user input. some time a wrong input from user can be like this.

**(amount1+ + 10 / 100)**

so at the time select query will not execute.

Comment: if you have a wrong user input - you should use the `form validation` library or check by yourself against - e.g if you expect an integer you simply transform usersdata like `$amount = intval($this->input->post('amount');` and thats it - you cant blame a db for a wrong user input, another possibility would be the use of `$this->db->escape(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sintakonte the user input that i mentioned is a formula from a formula builder.
so finally i did a simple trick to validate the query (formula).
do an **insertion** or **update** to the table with the **select** query.
In my scenario once i get the result from the select query i have to update
a column in a table.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->query("UPDATE table2 
                  JOIN ( 
                      SELECT (amount1+ 10 / 100) AS amnt, empID FROM test_table
                  ) AS calculationTB
                  ON calculationTB.empID = table2.empID AND 
                  SET fnTB.ssoEmployer=calculationTB.amnt");

if($this->db->trans_status() == false){                 
   return ['error' => 1, 'message' => 'Error massage'];          
}

$this->db->trans_commit();
```